# How to make a http request in retrofit with nd-json format?

Tags: json, kotlin, http, retrofit, ndjson

I am using kotlin/java for android. For a module I have to make request to our elasticsearch instance. For multiple queries `_msearch` elastic search accepts `nd-json` format.

```
{} // Index defined here
{} // Query and other settings here
// Repeat for other indexes
```

Currently I am working around it using a hardcoded string in json format where I change add the needed changes in request with;

```kotlin
"""
{}
{... ${Optional Key:Value as string} ... ${Optional Key:Value as string}}

""".trimIndent().toRequestBody("application/x-ndjson".toMediaTypeOrNull())
```

I want to know the proper/better way to do it, as you'd do it using serialisable/deserialisable class.